# ArrayFire seq to int c++

Tags: arrayfire

Imagine a gfor with a seq j...

If I need to use the value of the instance j as a index, who can I do that?

something like:

```
vector<double> a(n);
gfor(seq j, n){
    //Do some calculation and save this on someValue
    a[j] = someValue;
}
```

Someone can help me (again) ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution for this...

if someone had a better option, feel free to post...

First, create a seq with the same size of your gfor instances.
Then, convert that seq in a array.
Now, take the value of that line on array (it's equals the index)

```
seq sequencia(0, 200);
af::array sqc = sequencia;

//Inside the gfor loop
countLoop = (int) sqc(j).scalar<float>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach works, but breaks **gfors** parallelization as converting the index to a scalar forces it to be written from the gpu back to the host, slamming the breaks on the GPU.

You want to do it more like this :

```
af::array a(200);
gfor(seq j, 200){
   //Do some calculation and save this on someValue
   a[j] = af::array(someValue);  // for someValue a primitive type, say float
}
// ... Now we're safe outside the parallel loop, let's grab the array results
float results[200];
a.host(results)  // Copy array from GPU to host, populating a c-type array
```